# kendo ui datepicker required field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

Hi how to make Kendo UI DatePicker as a required field ? I added required attribute to an input element

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.POAStartDate, new { id="POAStartDate", Name="POAStartDate",data_id="POAStartDateCreate",required="true", data_class="poaDatePicker", @class="field-date", @readonly="readonly"})
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved, the problem was with readonly attribute, when u put readonly with required together on kendo ui datepicker, kendo ui validator doesn't validate it on reqiured rule, if u still want prevent user from entering wrong data in datepicker u should use custom validation rule here is an example http://jsbin.com/eleyeh/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

You should add `[Required]` to POAStartDate property of your model.

Comment: I am using kendo ui validation, i have disabled default jquery validate plugin which comes with default asp.net mvc template     <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false" />

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have added the **required** attribute manually, all you need to do now is to initialize the Kendo validator over your form which contains the datepicker. Check [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/validator/overview#basic-configuration-of-kendo-ui-validator).